# Symfony 4 alphanum validation without spaces

Tags: symfony

I want to use alnum type but without spaces, can i do something with that or i have to make my own type? I want to make username without spaces.

Like this here:

```
private $username;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 * @Assert\Type(type="alnum")
```

Comment: maybe is better to use Regex validation for this kind of string validation.

    /**
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern     = "/^[a-z0-9]+$/i",
     *     htmlPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
     * )
     */

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's much easier than creating a validator and work very good!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: If you have a good way, consider writing a self answer, or @MarcosRegis could turn his comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most powerful validation to solve this kind of trouble is the [Regex](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html) Constraint.

For your case (a very simple case) is enough to use (see [Length](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html))

```
/** 
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096, minMessage="...", maxMessage="...") 
 * @Assert\Regex( 
 * pattern = "/^[a-z0-9]+$/i", 
 * htmlPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$",
 * message="Your name must contain only letter or numbers"
 * ) 
 */
```

It is possible to unify both validator here in only one validator constraint but keep in mind that you lose the ability to show the exact error message if you have multiple conditions (like length and forbidden chars)

```
/** 
 * @Assert\Regex( 
 * pattern = "/^[a-z0-9]{1,4096}$/i", 
 * htmlPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4096}$", 
 * message="Your name must contain only letter or numbers and must have length between 1 and 4096"
 * ) 
 */
```

Where ***{1,4096}*** is the **min** and **max** values for limits of length string.

The *htmlPattern* and *message* are optional.

Comment: I recommand jusing 2 distinct validator because you would have 2 relevant messages for the end user.

Comment: @goto You are right! I will add to the answer this recomendation. Tnks!